# pandas bfill by interval to correct missing/invalid entries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

so I have a dataframe

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[numpy.nan,5],[numpy.nan,5],[2015,5],[2020,5],[numpy.nan,10],[numpy.nan,10],[numpy.nan,10],[2090,10],[2100,10]],columns=["value","interval"])

    value  interval
0     NaN         5
1     NaN         5
2  2015.0         5
3  2020.0         5
4     NaN        10
5     NaN        10
6     NaN        10
7  2090.0        10
8  2100.0        10
```

I need to backwards fill the NaN values based on their interval and the first non-nan following that index so the expected output is

```
    value  interval
0  2005.0         5  # corrected 2010 - 5(interval)
1  2010.0         5  # corrected 2015 - 5(interval)
2  2015.0         5  # no change ( use this to correct 2 previous rows)
3  2020.0         5  # no change
4  2060.0        10  # corrected 2070 - 10
5  2070.0        10  # corrected 2080 - 10 
6  2080.0        10  # corrected 2090 - 10 
7  2090.0        10  # no change (use this to correct 3 previous rows)
8  2100.0        10  # no change
```

I am at a loss as to how i can accomplish this task using pandas/numpy vectorized operations ...

I can do it with a pretty simple loop

```
last_good_value = None
fixed_values = []
for val,interval in reversed(df.values):
    if val == numpy.nan and last_good_value is not None:
       fixed_values.append(last_good_value - interval)
       last_good_value = fixed_values[-1]
    else:
       fixed_values.append(val) 
       if val != numpy.nan:
           last_good_value = val

print (reversed(fixed_values))
```

which strictly speaking works... but i would like to understand a pandas solution that can resolve the value, and avoid the loops (this is quite a big list in reality)

Comment: Do the missing values always come first in the group or would you need the possibility of filling later rows?

Comment: Hey thanks for asking, no they always fill backwards from a correct value further down (there also could be streaks of hundreds of invalid values, its not just 2 or 3 like in the example)

Comment: Are interval values always contiguous? Or there can be another interval 5 after the 10?

Comment: yes there could be an interval of 5 later in the dataset :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the position of the rows within groups sharing same 'interval' value.
Then, get the last value of each group.
What you are looking for is "last_value - pos * interval"

```
df = df.reset_index()
grouped_df = df.groupby(['interval'])
df['pos'] = grouped_df['index'].rank(method='first', ascending=False) - 1 
df['last'] = grouped_df['value'].transform('last')
df['value'] = df['last'] - df['interval'] * df['pos']
del df['pos'], df['last'], df['index']
```

Comment: this also looks awesome (although a bit more cryptic to me) ... and it seems slightly faster ... I will profile a bit more and if it is faster ill probably change this to the accepted answer :)

Comment: Sorry if not clear enough. I just figured that to get the data you want in the 'value' column, you just have to look at the 'interval' group it is in. You find what is the last 'value' in this group. Then you substract to it the 'interval' value N times, N being the row position inside the group. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: yeah it does ... i just had to stare at it for longer :P great answer and thanks a tonne ... exactly the output i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a grouping Series that groups the last non-null value with all `NaN` rows before it, by reversing with `[::-1]`. Then you can `bfill` and use `cumsum` to determine how much to subtract off of every row.

```
s = df['value'].notnull()[::-1].cumsum()
subt = df.loc[df['value'].isnull(), 'interval'][::-1].groupby(s).cumsum()

df['value'] = df.groupby(s)['value'].bfill().subtract(subt, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
    value  interval
0  2005.0         5
1  2010.0         5
2  2015.0         5
3  2020.0         5
4  2060.0        10
5  2070.0        10
6  2080.0        10
7  2090.0        10
8  2100.0        10
```

---

Because `subt` is subset to only the NaN rows, the `fill_value=0` ensures rows with values remain unchanged

```
print(subt)
#6    10
#5    20
#4    30
#1     5
#0    10
#Name: interval, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this looks promising

Comment: also this is very readable to me :) so thanks a tonne for this ... I might have to change to the other answer as the accepted (its maybe faster?) but this is still a great answer thanks!

Comment: the other answer is faster ... this one is more readable to me though ... but speed of this operation is critical to me so I changed the accepted answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley makes sense. I assume there's a difference in how optimized the groupby operations are. `bfill` never struck me as something particularly fast, and `rank` and `first` I think have fast paths.

Comment: sorry I probably screwed it up by listing bfill as my target :/